# How to Speed Up Blender 2.80 EEVEE Viewport?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to test Blender 2.80 and get used to it. It seems to be the most unique Blender update that I've used. I was able to get very fast interaction in Blender 2.78 Internal viewport using GLSL shading but in 2.80 the viewport is slow and unresponsive. Is there a way to turn on backface culling or other performance-enhancing options

I am trying to move on from OpenGL rendering PBR-based scenes in the Internal engine and move to a fully PBR-based rendering system called EEVEE.

Are there any backface culling or other features that are similar that will enhance my experience?

I have an Intel i5, Intel HD Graphics 3000, 8 GB RAM, installed on my Lenovo Thinkpad X220 Tablet Laptop (not actually a tablet).

Comment: Blender 2.8 are discouraged for final users at the moment

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to an unreleased feature, that is still work-in-progress.
.

Comment: I don't mind having it voted as off-topic. I'm just new to this forum and didn't know that it was a rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2.8 builds are snapshots of current development and are intended for testing a preview, not actual work. As parts, such as Eeevee, are not complete, there will be performance issues and bugs, and some features that are not yet present.

Given all of this, I would not yet be expecting any speed or performance features. And I wouldn't be worrying too much about their absence yet either.

Comment: You are totally right, @Sazerac and yet curiously [this happened today](https://twitter.com/hypersomniac_/status/871695953618759681)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos cool. Things are certainly coming along pretty quickly.

Comment: its beta now!!!!!!!!!